# combine multiple times Pandas DataFrame with counter in one colum

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi I have one DataFrame with 5 columns. The last column is numeric (1 for the first dataframe).

I tried to connect this dataframe 12 time = have in four columns the same values but in the last one increase by 1 to 12.

I've tried with a `while` loop, but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to do this?

In the end it should looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG5Vb.png)

```
exp_1 = pd.DataFrame({"a":["sth"],"b":["sth"],"c":["sth"],"numeric":[1]})
exp_2 = pd.DataFrame({"a":["sth"],"b":["sth"],"c":["sth"],"numeric":[2]})

finish=pd.concat([exp_1,exp_2])
```

but using one dataframe with 5000 rows

Comment: please post your input dataframe and then also post the expected dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I made somethin like that - I'm pretty sure there is any chance to make it better:
Code:

```
'''
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
exp_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','c'],'b':['d','e','f'],'c':[1,1,1]})
exp_1

'''
```

output:

```
    a   b   c
0   a   d   1
1   b   e   1
2   c   f   1
```

what I wanted to achieve:

```
'''
exp_2 = pd.DataFrame()
x = range(1,5)

for i in x:
    exp_2= pd.concat([exp_2,exp_1])
    exp_1['c'] += 1
    
exp_2
'''
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c
0   a   d   1
1   b   e   1
2   c   f   1
0   a   d   2
1   b   e   2
2   c   f   2
0   a   d   3
1   b   e   3
2   c   f   3
0   a   d   4
1   b   e   4
2   c   f   4
```